# React Native pass `props` through navigation container built by `createStackNavigator`

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I have a react-native app with top level `App.js` that is:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class App extends Component {
  render() { 
    return <AppStack {..this.props} /> 
  }
}

export withAuth(App)
```

Where the higher order component `withAuth` adds `user` and `authenticating` props to `App`:

```
const withAuth = (Component) =>
  class WithAuth extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        authenticating: true,
        user: false
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      // authenticating logic ...
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user)
          this.setState({
            authenticating: false,
            user: user
          })
        else
          this.setState({
            authenticating: false
          })
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (<Component user={this.state.user} authenticating={this.state.authenticating} {...this.props} />)
    }
  }
```

And the `AppStack` is:

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator( 
    { AppContainer, Profile }, 
    { initialRouteName : 'AppContainer' }
)
```

Note there is no code passing the `props` that was passed down from `class App` down to `AppContainer` and `Profile`.

Consequentially the `user` and `authenticating` props inside `AppContainer` is undefined.

```
class AppContainer extends Component {
  //  this.props.user is false and this.props.authenticating is true
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(`Debug Did mount with user: ${this.props.user}`, this.props.authenticating)
  }

  render() {
    // if I `export withAuth(AppContainer)`, then this prints the user information. but not if I log inside `componentDidMount`
    console.log(`Debug loaded with user: ${this.props.user}`, this.props.authenticating)
    return <Text>'hello world'</Text>
  }
}

export default AppContainer
```

I could wrap `AppContainer` inside `withAuth` and do `export default withAuth(AppContainer)`, but then `AppContainer` cannot read `this.props.user` property in `componentDidMount`, only in `render() { ... }`.

Ideally I would like to pass down the `user` and `authenticating` property from `AppStack`, how would I do so?

Note: for now I would like to not use `redux` if possible. This is a simple app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass props from your high order component to child screen through `screenProps`. Example:

```js
const withTest = Component => (
  class WithTest extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (<Component screenProps={{ user: "abc" }} />);
    }
  });
```

Check [Navigator Props](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props) for more detail.

Comment: This gets passed to your screen Components as `this.props.screenProps.user`